# PHP: How to catch text written in url after my domain name

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

Please see the sample link/ senario below.

www.mydomain.com/khaled

Default page on "www.mydomain.com" is index.php. There is no folder or file named "khaled". When the above URL is typed, i want index.php to be called and check the name "khaled" in database and show the relevent profile.

Problem: When i type the above URL error 404 is displayed.

.htaccess is an option but dont know what to write in it. tried the following line but it returned "Internal server error".

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ index.php?i=$1&p=$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

`$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` will hold this information in PHP. Your htaccess redirect should look something like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ /index.php?i=$1 [L]
```

Then in index.php `$_GET['i']` will hold the value of whatever is in the URL after the domain

You can obviously add more parameters in the same way, such as:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ /index.php?i=$1&j=$2 [L]
```

Then use `$_GET['i']` and `$_GET['j']` for your variables in PHP

Comment: Thanx for your quick response. When ever i type anything in my .htaccess, my browser ends up in error "Internal Server Error".

Note: My current .htaccess is empty and am trying it on my local computer with WAMP server installed.

Comment: I have tried the .htaccess suggestion of your its working on my webserver :D
Problem: on webserver, locaiotn of applicaiton is "www.mydomain.com/app-folder/khaled". Your code ends up on "www.mydomain.com/index.php". I need "www.mydoamin.com/app-folder/index.php" to handle this. Please suggest.

Comment: Could you post what else you have in your htaccess?

Comment: Nothing atall. only the line you suggested.

Comment: is mod-rewrite turned on in httpd.conf?